# Create docker image based on separate custom image that accepts command-line arguments

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I don't think I have the right title, but I'm not 100% sure what the correct one would be. I'm attempting to containerize a Python program that I have which can run as either a server or client based on CLI arguments. I was able to do it successfully by saying:

```
FROM python:3.5
ADD program/ program/
WORKDIR program/
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "program.py"]
```

which I can then run with `docker run -d program server <port> <protocol>` (or `client`) and it works properly.

I run into problems though, when I try to create images based on the previous image.

For example, if I want to create a server specific image, I tried:

```
FROM program
ENTRYPOINT ["server"]
```

and then my goal would be to run it by saying `docker run programServer <port> <protocol>`, however when I attempt that I get an `executable file not found in $PATH"` error.

Is there something that I'm missing, or are you not able to "daisy-chain" images this way?

Comment: Note that each `ENTRYPOINT` line overrides the previous `ENTRYPOINT` definition. So have you tried writing `ENTRYPOINT ["python", "program.py", "server"]`?

Comment: As an aside, you might be interested in the `CMD` directive to provide default arguments… e.g. `CMD ["<port>", "<protocol>"]` according to your example. See also [What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39408777/9164010)

Comment: @ErikMD Ahh, I didn't realize that. So does that mean I should remove the `ENTRYPOINT` statement from my first Dockerfile? It looks like adding your suggestion to my second Dockerfile gets it working.

Comment: No, it's unneeded to remove the `ENTRYPOINT` from your first Dockerfile (I elaborated on this in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65687930/9164010))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two remarks:

1. each image should contain one `ENTRYPOINT` and/or one `CMD` (either defined in the Dockerfile or inherited from its parent image);
2. each `ENTRYPOINT` line overrides the previous `ENTRYPOINT` definition (as a Docker container is intended to run **one** process, called the entrypoint).

So:

- you should just write `ENTRYPOINT ["python", "program.py", "server"]` in your second Dockerfile (for the child image);
- but you can just as well keep `ENTRYPOINT ["python", "program.py"]` in your first Dockerfile (for the parent image) as this causes no harm, and allows one to address rule 1 above.

But if a parent image is **only** intended to serve as a base image, never to be run "as is", and does not yield a natural entrypoint, you might just put a dummy `CMD` that prints a warning/error, for example, or a shell − see e.g. the [Dockerfile for `debian:10`](https://github.com/debuerreotype/docker-debian-artifacts/blob/dist-amd64/buster/Dockerfile#L3).

For more details on {`ENTRYPOINT`, `CMD`}, see also this SO answer: [What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39408777/9164010)

Comment: Thank you! The helps clear things up. The plan is for the parent image to only serve as a base image, so I will look in to the warning/error message.